# Generic and the erasure process

Tags: java, generics

I've a doubt reading this written in the Java [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/simple.html):

> In the introduction, we saw invocations of the generic type
>   declaration List, such as List. In the invocation (usually
>   called a parameterized type), all occurrences of the formal type
>   parameter (E in this case) are replaced by the actual type argument
>   (in this case, Integer).

but if there are no restrictions the formal type parameter is not replaced by Object?
Why is said that E is replaced by Integer?

Also, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), in the Java tutorial is said:

> To reference the generic Box class from within your code, you must
>   perform a generic type invocation, which replaces T with some concrete
>   value, such as Integer:

but, again, thanks to the erasure a compile time T in box class is replaced
by Object and not by Integer. Integer type is written only for casting operations.

In fact, still in the same [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) is said:

> During the type erasure process, the Java compiler erases all type
>   parameters and replaces each with its first bound if the type
>   parameter is bounded, or Object if the type parameter is unbounded.

I'm really confused. Which is the truth?
Is `T` replaced by `Integer` or by `Object`?

Comment: That quotation isn't talking about erasure.

Comment: so what does it meaning?

Comment: Which exactly is the question?

Comment: @Nicusan, I don't understand why is said that a type parameter is replaced by a type argument while, thanks to the erasure, if there are no bounds, type parameter is replaced by Object a compile time. So at run time when I create an instance of a generic class if I put <Integer>, <String>, etc. that don't replace type parameter but are used only for type checking, cast, etc.

Comment: When they say `In the invocation (usually called a parameterized type), all occurrences of the formal type parameter (E in this case) are replaced by the actual type argument (in this case, Integer).`, it doesn't mean that the replacement happens at compile time (when source files are turned into .class files). It's just about how the compiler sees the parameterized instances for further reference during source code development.

Answer (score 2):

You speak of different things.

The citations from the tutorial speak about type **instantiation**. This has nothing to do with type erasure, which is a IMHO misnamed concept, and simply means that the generic types are not available at runtime anymore.

But at compile time they are, and instantiation happens at compile time.

To answer your question, "at compile time" is a broad thing. THe following hapens all at compile time:

1. read source files
2. lexical analysis
3. parsing
4. ...
5. type checking
6. ...
7. code generation

The list is, by no means, complete, mind you.
However, as you see, during type checking, the compiler knows your type instantiations and can check them.

Later, it emits byte code, and since byte code has no way of representing generics, the types are "erased", which means, a cast is inserted here and there.

So, your assumption that "compile time" is somehow an instant where everything happens at once is not correct.

---

Further edit:

I think you take all this (i.e. the word "replace") too literally. For sure, the compiler has some data structures where the types and names and scopes of all items in the program are held.

Look, it's quite simple in principle, if we have:

```
static <X> List<X> meth(X[] arr) { .... }
```

And later, you do:

```
Integer arr = new Integer[100];
List<Integer> list = meth(arr);
Integer foo = list.get(1);
```

then you are instantiating the type of the meth method:

```
static List<Integer> meth(Integer[] arr) { .... }
```

The point of the generics is to say that `meth` works for any type. This is just what the compiler checks. And it will know, that, for **all X** if you pass an array of X, you get back a list of X, hence, since you passed Integer[], the result must be `List<Integer>` and the `list` assignment is correct. Furthermore, the compiler knows, that ** for all X **, if you get an element from a `List<X>`, it will be an X.

Therefore, the compiler notes and checks that foo is an `Integer`. Later, on code generation, it will insert there a cast to Integer, because, due to type erasure, the return value from List.get is Object.

Note also, that "replace" does not mean that the compiler somehow alters your code. It just creates (maybe temporary) from the generic type signature a non-generic one (by substituting - if you like this better - all the type parameters with their actual types), and uses this to check the type.

It is just like in math, if I say: Please replace the a with 42 and check if the equation is true:

a + 1 = 43

then it makes no sense to ask "where exactly" this replacement takes place. Most probably in your brain.

Comment: For me 'at compile time' means that the compiler make a source code compilation and if at compile time the erasure is also made how is it possible that generic type informations are still available or that Integer replaces T?

Comment: @xdevel2000 Answered concerning "compile time".

Comment: So, what are you saying is that before step 7 - code generation - where erasure happens type parameters are replaced by actual type arguments? But if this happens where that information (for example T is replaced by Integer) is stored and what is the reason if after the same information is discarded?

Comment: @xdevel2000 This actually happens multiple times. For example, every time you call List.get in the source code will the type of List.get get instantiated (at compile time!) with the actial type, and checked. See above.

Comment: I really appreciated your answer, however, I think that when an instance of a parameterized object is created the compiler "checks" (and not "replace") that the actual type (in that case, Integer) is a subtype of the bound of the type parameter (in that case Object). If it is not, the code will not compile. In fact you wrote: """Therefore, the compiler notes and checks that foo is an Integer. Later, on code generation, it will insert there a cast to Integer, because, due to type erasure, the return value from List.get is Object.""". Probably it's me who can not understand...

Comment: @xdevel2000 - `List.get` is already compiled. It's signature tells that it returns Object. The JVM would not allow to assign a Object reference to a variable that holds an Integer reference. Therefore, the return value of List.get must be casted. The compiler knows hat it is safe to cast an Object from a List<Integer> to Integer, and inserts the cast in the bytecode. You can check with javap whether I say the truth.

Answer (score 1):

```
the formal type parameter is not replaced by Object?
```

Generic type represented as `Object` in runtime. But you can get information about `<YourType>` with reflection. Erasure relates to compatibility with old clases. It was a bad idea. [Article about it](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html).

Comment: What I understand is that at compile time the erasure replace type parameters by Object or by an upper bound type. After, at run-time the reflection or other API like getClass().getName() inspects what that object references (Integer, String, etc.).